# What will be python code for applying percentile in Aggfunc in a pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pivot-table, percentile

```py
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Item name list', 'Date'], aggfunc={'p2d_quantity':np.sum,'timestamps':np.percentile(99.5)})
```

Getting error as:

> "TypeError: _percentile_dispatcher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'q'"

Answer (score 0):

Use lambda function:

```
np.percentile(99.5)
```

change to:

```
lambda x: np.percentile(x, 99.5)
```